# How can a worksheet be shared on team drive through pygsheet

Tags: python-2.7, pygsheets

I have worksheet with 2 sheets and Need to share it on team Drive. 
I read the documentation on pyghsheet ,In share `pygsheet.share` 
 method we can pass group/user , But how can we share on a teamDrive.

```
gc= pygsheets.authorize(outh_nonlocal=True)
gc.enableTeamDriveSupport = True

gc.teamDriveId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
print " aurhorization done"
sheet= gc.create("Price-"+oldDate)
sheet.add_worksheet("Sheet2",rows=1000,cols=15)
workSheet=sheet[0]
workSheet.set_dataframe(finalPrice,(1,1))
workSheet=sheet[1]
workSheet.set_dataframe(intermediate,(1,1))
sheet.share(??????)
```

How it can be achieved.

Comment: what is "share on a teamDrive"? teamDrive is a drive not a user

Comment: I mean uploading sheet on team drive

Comment: So you want to create a sheet on the teamDrive rt ?

Comment: I am creating sheet though pandas dataframe and then want to upload on team drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to create a sheet on a teamDrive, just specify the id of a folder where you want the sheet to be created

```
gc= pygsheets.authorize(outh_nonlocal=True)
gc.enableTeamDriveSupport = True

gc.teamDriveId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
print " aurhorization done"
sheet= gc.create("Price-"+oldDate, parent_id="xxxxxxxx") # your folder id as parent
sheet.add_worksheet("Sheet2",rows=1000,cols=15)
workSheet=sheet[0]
workSheet.set_dataframe(finalPrice,(1,1))
workSheet=sheet[1]
workSheet.set_dataframe(intermediate,(1,1))
```